# Error in creating a trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: triggers, mariadb

[sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4BAm.png)

error :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER `issue_book` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `book_issue_log`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.due_date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: phpMyAdmin does not have triggers! It is NOT a database its a tool written in PHP. Terminology does matter specially in a question. MySQL does as does mariaDB

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.